# Can clear activity be linked to hidden activity?

Tags: anonymity, security, whonix

I'm using whonix for a good deal of activity but I'm very new to it and Linux. will using my computer for personal information while not running whonix or tor compromise my anonymity?  What about at the same time?

Is it possible if I use my computer for personal information on the internet without Tor or Whonix enabled for that personal info going over the clear internet to be linked to my activity on Tor? If I put my name all over this computer and do various things (email, facebook, etc.) without Tor enabled, will that make it easier to identify my computer/me while Tor or Whonix are enabled? I'm not using these personal sites while Tor is running because that seems like it would defeat the purpose.

Can this be explained to me, I have been reading all the FAQs I can find about Tor anonymity and I still don't have an understanding of how it interacts or is affected by clear activity.

My ISP can see my activity when I'm not using Tor/Whonix, then it can also see that sometimes I am using Tor, correct? So is this link of my personal life to this computer a bad idea for my Tor safety?

Comment: Drrift, This site was created to discuss the use of Tor specifically. Unfortunately, general security and privacy questions are outside the scope of this site. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @RobertCartaino 
I realize this site is for Tor specifically, that's why I'm asking my question here because the whonix support page linked me here for Tor help. This is a Tor specific question and if anything is highly similar to this previously answered question: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/86/is-tors-security-compromised-if-other-services-are-connecting-in-the-clear
Let me rephrase maybe, can using my machine freely on the internet when not running Tor on it compromise Tor activity, and will keeping highly personal information on this computer endanger my anonymity in whonix?

Comment: Can this be addressed by a moderator that has been a member of this forum for more than a month?

Comment: Drrift Absolutely, if you would like to clarify the question about how it relates to Tor, go for it. If a moderator feels I made an incorrect call, they should feel free to correct it. If all else fails, you can always start a [meta](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com) discussion.

Comment: The first two paragraphs are indeed a duplicate of: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/86/is-tors-security-compromised-if-other-services-are-connecting-in-the-clear Please remove them. `My ISP can see my activity when I'm not using Tor/Whonix, then it can also see that sometimes I am using Tor, correct?` - Correct. `So is this link of my personal life to this computer a bad idea for my Tor safety?` - Always better to compartmentalize. If you do that or not is up to you.

Comment: @Drrift Although this question is on topic now, but still seem to be a duplicate of [Is Tor's security compromised if other services are connecting in the clear?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/86/is-tors-security-compromised-if-other-services-are-connecting-in-the-clear). Please have a look and see if you get your answer there. Otherwise, rephrase your question and ping me (or other mods) to re-open your question. It's important for us to make sure you got your answer.