# Is my anonymity compromised when I am in the clearnet with another browser while surfing with Tor?

Tags: anonymity, security, browsers

Sometimes I am surfing anonymously via Tor and parallelly with a regular browser in the clearnet. Is it anyhow unsecure to do so? Should I use Tor exclusively when I want to remain anonymous?

(There is a somehow similar [question and answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/86/1353), but I would like to know about using a regular browser beside Tor.)

Comment: As you said, this question already exists. Limiting it to a browser vs. anything else doesn't matter; it's all web traffic. If anyone feels differently or that I've jumped the gun here, please nominate for reopening.

Comment: You're most likely right. I just asked this question specifically pointing to another browser as most users know what "another browser" is, but they might not have the understanding about "services".

Comment: In general, it's best to keep all answers in one place. If you want to make sure a question is clear, please edit the original question. Thanks for using Tor.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I think, as with the other question, the short answer is no, but there is some possibility of sophisticated attacks that might be able to tell that your clearnet connection and the one you are making over Tor come from the same place.